# Visual studio code Go to implementation not working ( ctr + F12) not working

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

VS code cannot route to the implementation of an interface. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> is not working too. Is there anyway to fix this problem?  Visual Studio code version `1.19.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and see your key maps.

Another really useful option is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: I know that. `Ctrl + 12` is listed in shortcut command but it is not working. I mean no action triggered. It seems like it cannot find the implemented class of the interface. On eclipse it is working as normal.

Comment: Then I guess your implementation is in the library. :)

Answer (score 0):

As for scss files i got this problem after i changed

```
// Allows to display errors.
"scss.showErrors": false
```

to

```
"scss.showErrors": true
```

in Settings...
gl

Answer (score 0):

The following answer helped me with the same issue. It enumerates steps to enable/disable all extensions.

[VSCode "go to definition" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984136/217440)