# How to setup VS Code for C++ with clangd support?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, language-server-protocol

*Disclaimer: I am totally new to VS Code, so, please, be gentle with me. :-)*

I am trying to set up [**VS Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for **C++**.
However, I explicitly want to set it up so that it uses the [*Language Server Protocol*](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) to communicate with [`clangd`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd.html) when handling C++-files.

I already installed `clangd` on my (Ubuntu Linux) system and the official  [*"vscode-clangd"*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) extension from the VS Code market, and I also adjusted its settings so that `clangd` should be found by it.

However, now I am lost.
When I open a `*.cpp` or `*.hpp` file VS Code recommends some other extensions to me (e.g. the official Microsoft [*"C/C++"*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension with IntelliSense support) but I do not see where and how `clangd` does help me at all.

Using Microsoft's "C/C++" extension seems to work out of the box but how can I use `clangd`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 50):

I can share some of my configures.

Microsoft "C/C++" extension is great for debugging, I think you should install it.

Meanwhile, Clangd provides a more accurate result in finding references.
So, My suggestion is to keep the official C/C++ extension for debugging but disable its IntelliSense. Put below lines to your settings.json

```
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled",
        
    "clangd.path": "/path/to/your/clangd",
    "clangd.arguments": ["-log=verbose", 
                         "-pretty", 
                         "--background-index", 
                         //"--query-driver=/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++", //for cross compile usage
                         "--compile-commands-dir=/path/to/your/compile_commands_dir/"]
```

**Note**: The directory `/path/to/your/compile_commands_dir/` should have a file `compile_commands.json`.

Always refer to [the official website](https://clangd.llvm.org/config), there are more settings like filtering out compile param etc.
When correctly configured,  you will see the output of clangd from OUTPUT windows next to Problems and Terminal.

[image]

Comment: I have "clangd.arguments" configured but it is blurred in settings.json, what does that mean?

Comment: @frogEye It normally means this feature is outdated or doesn't exist, I'm not sure why it's your case because this feature surely exists and not outdated. Can you try to add another line of config `"clangd.checkUpdates": true` and see how's it going?

Comment: Thanks @George Zheng, I figured out the all issue was due to opening the workspace. The extension was not working with workspace but when I tried to open my code as a folder it worked.

Comment: Few days back, i came to know about LSP and clangd. While configuring it, i came across the term "comple-commands" but i can't understand what is does as my LSP is working without it. Can you please tell me a bit about it and how can i get it for myself. I am using gcc compiler for c++

Comment: @GauravAggarwal as its name suggested, it's a database in json file to inform clangd how to process it. if you are using cmake you and enable it by `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)`. if not you can try this project [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear)

Comment: FYI, if `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled"`, then the `"C_Cpp.autocomplete"` and `"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles"` settings aren't needed since [they'll be ignored](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4979#issuecomment-723224009).

Comment: I see `clangd` in the drop down of the output window but not Clang language server like yours. Is that ok too or is somethinh wrong?

Comment: @roulette01 it's correct. my snapshot is outdated.

Comment: For line "--compile-commands-dir=/path/to/your/compile_commands_dir/"] , how I can fill ?

Comment: Do you actually have to provide compile commands path? Isn't this done automatically?

Comment: @glades read my answer post.

Comment: @starball That means I don't need to do anything since clangd will search under build/. Nice!

Answer (score 7):

It should work without any configuration.
I have tested that on Windows and it works just fine—I have no C/C++ extension installed in Visual Studio Code, just `vscode-clangd` and it reports errors, provides code completion, etc.
That means the extension works, because there are no such features in the "core" Visual Studio Code.
Visual Studio Code does still suggest popular C/C++ extensions, but you can ignore that, it doesn't mean that `vscode-clangd` isn't working.

Note that the file you are editing has to have a standard extension like `.cpp` or `.c` to be recognized and acted upon by `vscode-clangd`.
See [the extension's source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/fd2d6d99444e790680fbfec823f16e7a45a6d1b3/clangd/clients/clangd-vscode/src/extension.ts#L34) for the list of all supported extensions.

For simple projects, having no configuration may be enough, but for more complex ones, you will of course need to let Clang know things like include directories, compilation flags, etc.
This can be done by creating a `compile_flags.txt` file where you type arguments for Clang, one per line.
You can put this file into the same folder as your source files or anywhere up the tree.
After editing this file, you have to restart Visual Studio Code, so that the changes take effect.

Alternatively, you can create (or let CMake generate) a `compile_commands.json` file.
It has the following syntax:

```
[
  { "directory": "/home/user/llvm/build",
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang++ -Irelative -DSOMEDEF=\"With spaces, quotes and \\-es.\" -c -o file.o file.cc",
    "file": "file.cc" },
  ...
]
```

See [Clang docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

See [the VS Code Clangd extension's Project Setup docs](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/blob/master/README.md#project-setup), which state:

> you must tell clangd how your project is built (compile flags). [A compile_commands.json file](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) can usually be generated by your build system (e.g. with CMake, by setting `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1`).
>
> See [Project Setup](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup) in the clangd documentation for details and alternatives.

In the linked clangd docs, you'll see:

> `compile_commands.json`
> This file provides compile commands for every source file in a project. It is usually generated by tools.
>
> clangd will look in the parent directories of the files you edit looking for it, and also in subdirectories named `build/`. For example, if editing `$SRC/gui/window.cpp`, we search in `$SRC/gui/`, `$SRC/gui/build/`, `$SRC/`, `$SRC/build/`, …

#### Info for people generating compile_commands.json with CMake

Since CMake generates the compile commands database in root of the build tree, unless you're doing an in-source build, you'll probably need to either

- configure clangd to look in the build tree

  - If you're using a clangd config file, see https://clangd.llvm.org/config#compilationdatabase
  - The VS Code Clangd extension provides a setting `clangd.arguments`, where you can pass `--compile-commands-dir=...`
- or copy the file manually to your source tree. See also [Copy compile_commands.json to project root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57464766/11107541) (or [you can create a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76577093/11107541)).

See also the docs for [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) (note that it's only supported at the time of this writing if you're using a Ninja or Makefiles generator). You'll probably want to add that copy's path to your .gitignore.

If you are using the CMake Tools extension: The docs say to use `-D...`, which you do if you're calling the configuration command yourself via commandline. If you're doing it through the VS Code CMake Tools extension, you can either use the `cmake.configureSettings` setting it contributes, or write a [CMake configure preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset) and use the `cacheVariables` property (since CMake Tools supports CMake presets).