# Copy compile_commands.json to project root folder

Tags: cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` in the root of my project with `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` turned on.

I am building target inside a folder and is called via `add_subdirectory`. The folder has its own `CMakeLists.txt` file.

`compile_commands.json` is built in the root of the binary directory, and I want to copy it to root of source directory after running the cmake command.

I have tried two approaches.

1. `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command`.
   I created a dummy target. I used this target for `add_custom_command` to copy the file but it does not trigger command in `add_custom_command`.
2. `file(COPY ...)`
   The first time the command is triggered, the `compile_commands.json` is not created via cmake. I don't want to run cmake command twice to get copy `compile_commands.json` to root of source folder.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.8)
project(exec LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_subdirectory("DirectoyWithTarget")

add_custom_target(copy_compile_commands
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json)
add_custom_command(
  TARGET copy_compile_commands
  PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json
  )
```

The `compile_commands.json` file is not copied to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. This means the `add_custom_command` is not triggered.

Comment: I don't think it is possible as of now to copy that file during cmake invocation. You could work with a symlink or hook it into a target so it gets copied when you call make.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [cmake.copyCompileCommands](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#cmake-copycompilecommands), if you use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [vscode-cmake-tools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools).

Example:

```
"cmake.copyCompileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_commands.json"
```

Answer (score 6):

Haven't tested these much, but here are two cmake based solutions I came up with.

#### Option 1

Less code, but always runs.

```
add_custom_target(
    copy-compile-commands ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    )
```

#### Option 2

More code, but sets up dependencies so doesn't run unless need to. Can handle case where you delete compile_commands.json in binary directory.

```
# Copy to source directory
add_custom_target(
    copy-compile-commands ALL
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    )
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    DEPENDS
        # Unlike "proper" targets like executables and libraries, 
        # custom command / target pairs will not set up source
        # file dependencies, so we need to list file explicitly here
        generate-compile-commands
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    )

# Generate the compilation commands. Necessary so cmake knows where it came
# from and if for some reason you delete it.
add_custom_target(generate-compile-commands
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    )
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -B${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -S${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option to create a symlink. See [the `file(CREATE_LINK ...)`  command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#create-link). Ex.

```
file(CREATE_LINK
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json"
  SYMBOLIC
)
```

The advantage of that would be that you only have to do it once. It's pretty simple to do, and you wouldn't need to update contents when compile_commands.json changes.