# How to use vscode-clangd with c++11?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

How to conf vscode-clangd to use c++11 for lint?

I added both `complie_commands.json` and `complie_flags.txt` in workshop.

```
workshop
|-complie_commands.json
|-complie_flags.txt
|-list.cpp
```

---

complie_commands.json

```
[
   { "directory": "pathto/workshop/",
     "command": "/opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7/root/usr/bin/clang++ -o file *cpp -std=c++11"}
]
```

compile_flags.txt

```
-std=c++11
```

---

It couldn't recognize `auto` with error:

```
'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
```

Comment: @TonyTannous: "vscode" is "Visual Studio Code", which is only in name and looks related to the regular Visual Studio.

Comment: I'd expect C++11 to be detected from`compile_commands.json`, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885784/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-c-with-clangd-support

Answer (score 2):

Set `cppStandard` in [c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) to `c++11`. e.g.:

```
{
  "env": {
    "myDefaultIncludePath": ["${workspaceFolder}", "${workspaceFolder}/include"],
    "myCompilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-7"
  },
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Linux",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "includePath": ["${myDefaultIncludePath}", "/another/path"],
      "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks"],
      "defines": ["FOO", "BAR=100"],
      "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/include/config.h"],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++11",
      "compileCommands": "/path/to/compile_commands.json",
      "browse": {
        "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the Microsoft C/C++ is disabled.

Comment: @abhi3700 I don't imagine any of the C++ plugin works if it is disabled?

Comment: @Alan Birtles Actually, Microsoft C/C++ extension sucks. LLVM clangd, give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

### Note: I've Q&A this kind of question with more details in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185524/17001641)

#### Intro

[clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) first check for a [compilation database](https://clangd.llvm.org/design/compile-commands#compilation-databases) in the directory containing the source file, and then walk up into parent directories until we find one.

compilation database can be:

1. `complie_commands.json`: which usually generated by a build system like CMake:

```
# add the following line to your `CMakeLists.txt` script:
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

- Every "{...}" in .json file corresponds to a single file(**tedious and error-prone** to write by hand)
- See: [Generating a JSON compilation database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/generating-a-json-compilation-database.html)

2. `compile_flags.txt`: for simple projects like yours(for **all** files).

#### Solution:

As for you, just delete your `complie_commands.json` keep your `compile_flags.txt`.

> If you really want to try, see [format and example](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html#format)
> and try.

---

#### Not Recommended way

You can fix this by adding these config file. (if no compilation database is found)

1. `cmd/ctrl + shift + p`: Preferences: Open User Settings （JSON）
2. Add a single line into your `settings.json` file:

```json
"clangd.fallbackFlags": [
    "-std=c++11",
    "-std=c99"  // in case you need to write C
  ],
```

3. `cmd/ctrl + shift + p`: clangd: Restart language server

Boom, it worked now!

> It will cause `.h` file error... So not recommended for now.