clang-tidy in CMake fails to build constexpr lambda function
I'm using VSCode v1.89.1 with the g++ v12.1 and/or clang v14.0 compilers. I want to add clang-tidy to my build using CMakeLists.txt but have found myself in a situation that I don't understand.
For a little backstory, if you have the "Clang-Tidy" v0.5.1 extension installed in VSCode you should remove it as it is unmaintained and the github repo is readonly. The clangd v0.1.28 extension works much better.
To my CMakeLists.txt I added this:
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy)

With this line inserted, my was-working build starts to fail with these errors:
constexpr variable 'unchanged' must be initialized by a constant expression [clang-diagnostic-error]
non-literal type '(lambda at .../units.h:19:42)' cannot be used in a constant expression

Here is a reduced sample program showing the code structure:
typedef double (*cvtFn)(double);
static constexpr cvtFn unchanged = [](double d) { return d; };

int main()
{
    auto rv = unchanged( 0.1 );
    return static_cast<int>( rv );
}

I've determined that the issue is that this syntax requires C++17 to compile, which I have set in my CMakeLists.txt as set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17), but clang-tidy is not using the C++17 syntax. Based on a comment to the accepted answer here, my understanding is that CMake should propagate all the compiler values to clang-tidy.
The CMake documentation is completely opaque to me - why does it (CMake version 3.22.1) fail the build here? According to the documentation for this setting it should only be a warning.
Is there a simple incantation I'm overlooking?

It requires at least C++17, you didn't seem to set the appropriate C++ standard to clang-tidy.

Please post a [mcve] with the CMakeLists.txt

@cigen I should remove that last statement - it was referring to the problem that started me down the path and is not relevant. The code compiles at godbolt. I don't know why clang-tidy complains, and I don't know why CMake fails when clang-tidy complains. The documentation page for set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY... says it just issues warnings.

@273K You're correct - C++17 is required to support that syntax, so my issue is that I'm expecting the value for CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD to be propagated to clang-tidy and it's not happening. I tried to create a minimal CMakeLists.txt but I can't get it to run clang-tidy at all. Still poking at it...

So now: clangd is running and performing much better, but it's still giving errors on C++17 code. The editor is showing errors but it's not clear to me if this is impacting the compiler, which is GCC. I have found that the --std=c++17 argument is in build/compile_commands.json and that if I change my compiler to clang 14, both (a) that file is updated and (b) clangd starts treating the code as C++17. This may be becoming a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885784/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-c-with-clangd-support ; with the answer that clangd 14 is incompatible with g++ 12.
