# VSCode 'Go to definition' not working only in big projects

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode for C language professionally almost everyday for +1 year. Right now, I hit with something that is really affecting my productivity.

When I open a big project, the features "Go to definition, Go to declaration, Peek..." etc don't work. I don't know how to describe how 'big' the project is. There are source files with +26k lines and it can take up to 45 min to compile. When I work with a more reasonably sized project, I have no issues, so until now I assumed this was a limitation of the program due to the size of my project and resigned myself. Now, I'm really bothered at this point and would like to find a solution.

What strikes me is that searching in the whole project (Ctrl + Shift + F) is blazing fast and works brilliantly, so VS seems to be capable of 'handling' this big project.

- C/C++ extension from Microsoft last version v0.28.3
- VSCode last version 1.46.1
- Windows 10

Do you think there is a solution for this? Have you used VSCode with massive projects?

Edit: by 'don't work' I mean, it tries to perform the action but stays 'thinking' indefinitely.

Comment: Well, 26k lines is not "big". If you have 6 or 7 digit numbers of lines, I would call it "big", and beginning with 7 digits, "massive". It's not a pet project either, it's just small- to mid-sized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most propably it is not "Not working" but just "pretty slow". This is a known problem for C/C++ projects using the C/C++ extension for Visual studio code. The Indexer for intellisense needs some time (especially if you are not limiting it via `limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders` or something like that). You could try reducing the amount of parsed files by using explizit browse paths in your `c_cpp_properties.json` like

```
"browse": {
  "path": [
    "/usr/include/",
    "/usr/local/include/",
    "${workspaceRoot}/../include",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir1",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir2",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir3/src/c++",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir5",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir6/src",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir7/src",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dir4"
],
```

and excluding for example IDE/SDK files where you do not need autocompletion/Go To Symbol/Go to definition.

For more explanation see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1695

Comment: This sort of did the trick. I have to wait 2 to 4 s sometimes for it, but at least it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**`clangd` plugin**

For C I've had very good results with the `clangd` plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd which integrates [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/) into vscode.

This plugin parses code using clang based on a [`compile_commads.json` database](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) which contains the exact compilation commands as produced by the build system, and as a result tends to produce the most accurate results possible.

I have covered it's setup in more detail at: [VSCode "go to definition" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341849/vscode-go-to-definition-not-working/76193270#76193270)