# How to config java version in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I installed OpenJDK 18 in my Fedora 36 and installed "Extension Pack for Java" on my Visual Studio Code. In my machine, there have 3 versions of java:
[image]

But when I create a maven project and run it in VS Code, I found it used java 11.
[image]
How can I configure VS code to let it run projects on Java 18?

Comment: You need to edit the confit file as shown here "Configure Runtime for Projects": https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects

Comment: Thank you  @sorifiend  for your hint. I will write the answer in detail.

Comment: FYI: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To config to the right JDK in VS Code.
Open File -->Settings --> Java --> Configuration:Runtimes -->[Edit in Setting.json]
add:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-18",
        "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-18.0.1.1.2-1.rolling.fc36.x86_64",
        "sources" : "/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-18.0.1.1.2-1.rolling.fc36.x86_64/lib/src.zip",
        "javadoc" : "/usr/share/javadoc/java-18-openjdk-18.0.1.1.2-1.rolling.fc36.x86_64/api",
        "default":  true
    }
]
```

The path is the "$JAVA_HOME" if you run
`$sudo alternatives --config java` and the result is

```
+ 3 java-latest-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-18.0.1.1.2-1.rolling.fc36.x86_64/bin/java)
```

then JAVA_HOME is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-18.0.1.1.2-1.rolling.fc36.x86_64`

The source, if you install `sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk-src.x86_64` the source code will be $JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip

To find the Javadoc if you install "`java-latest-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64`",
you can use command `rpm -pl java-latest-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64` to check the installation location.

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, search for and select **Java: Configure Java Runtime** .

[image]

*or click the three dots after the Java project and select Configure Java Runtime.*

[image]

Select the version you want from the drop-down options.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, my OS is Fedora, and the VS code is 1.70 insider. So things are a little bit different. The last pix is different, there is no drop-down list. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS,

```
## Install java 11 by brew
brew install java11

## For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk

## edit settings.json
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
{
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home",
    "javadoc": "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
    "default": true
}
```

The "path" could be "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home". They are the same.