# Advice in fixing Vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode on my windows 11 using jdk 21, but when my prof ask us to install netbeans version 8, i have a hard time in installing because it says that may jdk 21 is not compatible with netbeans 8, then may prof  make me download jdk 8 and jre 8, now that the netbeans version 8 is running in may laptop. My vscode Don't run anymore. How can i change the default jdk in vscode because jdk 21 is still installed in my laptop, but vscode can't recognize it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PqnO.png)

Can you give me some advice on how to fix it, than you

Comment: having it installed doesn't mean it's being used by you IDE. This is configuration of your IDE.

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73145854/how-to-config-java-version-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: FYI: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Comment: You can have multiple JDKs installed. And, [*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/) is your friend.

Comment: Another option is to change your windows path variables to point to whatever java version you want at the moment. Remember that for coding and compiling your IDE needs a jdk.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code, it is from the Java runtime. It would appear that your profile has links to both versions of Java, which is causing incompatibilities between the compiler and the run time. The quickest way to resolve this would be to remove all versions of Java from your system. Then re-install version 8 and rebuild all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setting to configure java17 or higher to activate the Java language server.

```
    // Specifies the folder path to the JDK (17 or more recent) used to launch the Java Language Server. This setting will replace the Java extension's embedded JRE to start the Java Language Server.
    // On Windows, backslashes must be escaped, i.e.
    // "java.jdt.ls.java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0_3"

    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
```

You can then configure the version of java used by the java extension using the settings below.

```
    // Map Java Execution Environments to local JDKs.

    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_341",
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
            "default": true,
        }
    ],
```