# "Go to Definition" not working in VS Code with Robot Framework Language Server

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

When I use the context menu on a keyword in a file and select "Go to Definition" I'm always getting a pop-up for No Definition Found.

I've got the Robot Framework Language Server extension installed. Python (3.11) and Pylance.

I've tried disabling/reenabling extensions and restarting code and changing the Python language server.

How can I reenable the go to functionality, please?

I've tried the following:
[VSCode "go to definition" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341849/vscode-go-to-definition-not-working)

This functionality was previously working with my VS Code / Python / Robot Framework setup.

[image]

Comment: Try using `"python.analysis.extraPaths": []` to add source paths.

Answer (score 0):

### Instances Where This Issue May Occur

More context for your code would be needed to know if this is the case, but I can come up with a situation where this could occur. However, if you are truly getting this issue everywhere, then unfortunately, I don't believe this is the problem.

For example, if you attempt to use a keyword somewhere in a Robot Framework file where a keyword is not meant to be used, you would have the Go to definition option, but it would not work.

Ex. (keywords cannot be used in Variables section):

```
*** Variables ***
Set Suite Variable    ${customer_name}    ${forename}
```

Another ex. (keyword is not properly indented and is therefore treated as a test name):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Some test
    Log    hello world
Set Suite Variable     ${customer_name}    ${forename}
```

Go to definition should work in the below example. If it does not, then I don't know what is causing the problem.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Some test
    Set Suite Variable     ${customer_name}    ${forename}
```

### Possibilities to Rule Out

I also use the Robot Framework Language Server extension. I have seen instances where Go to Definition does not work that do not appear to apply in your example. I'd still like to go over these examples just to review what possible causes I think we can rule out, and for anyone else reading this who might be in one of these situations:

- The extension is not using your python installation (the path to python can be set in the extension's settings). If this were the case, Go to Definition wouldn't even display as an option, so this can be ruled out.
- The keyword is defined in a file that the file you are currently in does not have access to. The `Settings` section should provide access using either the `Library` or `Resource` setting. I see this sometimes in `.resource` files because the `.robot` file that calls those keywords has the appropriate resources listed, which means you won't have any runtime problems, but the extension is unable to find the definition. This is not the case in your example because you are using a `BuiltIn` keyword.
- Issues with PYTHONPATH (also something you can set in the extension's settings). This can happen you write custom keywords in python. Once again, this is not the case in your example because you are using a `BuiltIn` keyword.

Comment: Our project uses centralised resoiurce files for all our resources (and libraries).
I've checked my system path to ensure it is pointed at correct python installation.